# Eiffel Studio ARM Apple Silicon M1

Tags: apple-m1, eiffel, eiffel-studio-20.05

I am hoping to create some software with Eiffel & Eiffel Studio

I have a Mac mini with the Apple M1 Arm Processor.

Is there a port of EiffelStudio to native Mac M1?

Does Eiffel Studio support native MacOS Windowing or is it still requiring Windows?

Comment: errr.  dumb spell correct.  Does Eiffel Studio still require X Windows?

Answer (score 1):

EiffelStudio 21.11 download page does not list a native build for macOS running on M1, only on x86-64. Provided that there are builds for Linux running on ARM, there should be no obstacles to make a build for M1, though.

As to the GUI part, starting from 21.11, non-Windows installations of EiffelStudio rely on GTK 3, that utilizes Quartz API. So, it should not require X Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For now, EiffelStudio for macos M1 is not yet built officially.
However you can download https://ftp.eiffel.com/pub/beta/nightly/PorterPackage_106046.tar and compile it yourself.
For usual macosx-x86-64 machine, the command from the extracted folder is

./compile_exes macosx-x86-64

You may need to get inspired by config files from PorterPackage/C/CONFIGS/  to have a dedicated config for macos on M1 .